# Unable to instantiate activity with inheritance classes

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm new Android developer and I am developping a game with GoogleMap API v2 on Android smartphones.

When I want to start my game in training mode, I have this compilation error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.epig_lab.game/com.epig_lab.game.GameModeTraining}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is my code:

`Intent inent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameModeTraining.class);`

And classes:

```
public abstract class AGameMode extends Activity // implements View.OnClickListener, OnMapClickListener
{
    JSONArray j_city;
    String capital_city = "..."
    String[] city_already_choosen = new String[capital_city.length() + 1];
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);

    AGameMode()
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_attack);

        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

        // Other supported types include: MAP_TYPE_NORMAL,
        // MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID and MAP_TYPE_NONE
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        //map.setOnMapClickListener(this);

        try {
            j_city = new JSONArray(capital_city);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And a subclass:

```
public class GameModeTraining extends AGameMode {

    GameModeTraining()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }

}
```

And this in my Android.Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.epig_lab.game.GameModeTraining"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GAMEMODETRAINING" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Comment: The log should show the full NullPointerException stack trace. Look at that for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Activities are managed by the Android OS. This means that you should not write your own constructors for Activities and you should not instantiate them directly.
You have to obey the [Activity lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

==> remove the constructors and move all initializations into the `onCreate` method.